# C++11 alignof on non-static data members without an object

Tags: c++, alignment, c++11

In C++11 can I use alignof on non-static data members without an object?

If i have a class, for example

```
class A 
{
   int num; 
   unsigned char letter;
};
```

can I use `alignof(A::letter);` similarly to the extended sizeof syntax (e.g `sizeof(A::letter);`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The changes that allowed this for sizeof also apply to alignof. [Here's](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2253.html) one of the papers that propose the changes for sizeof. Basically it's done by changing the meaning of unevaluated operands, and alignof uses an unevaluated operand.

Trying it in a compiler that claims to support alignof, Clang (top of trunk), worked for me.